# Difference between momentum calculated from wavefunction and momentum computed by energy formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum

Take a quantum well, for example. The energy of an electron is given by:

$E_n=k_n n^2$. Moreover, we know that the [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) of an electron with energy $E_n$ is given by: $p=mv=m(2T/m)^{1/2}$, where $T=E_n$ is the kinectic energy. However, the momentum can be calculated using the momentum operator and the wavefunction of the state.

My question is: in this case of a quantum well, what is the difference between both approaches? How does this answer applies to a more general case?

Comment: You can see that the method you proposed is not valid if the system is not in an energy eigenstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $p = m(2T/m)^{1/2}$ is wrong. You got that by stipulating that $T=p^2 / 2m$ but that is only true for particles traveling in a constant potential.

For a particle in one dimension, and working in the position basis, the momentum operator is $\hat{p} = -i\hbar (d/dx)$ and the energy operator (Hamiltonian) is $\hat{H} = \hat{p}^2/2m = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (d^2/dx^2)$. When you respect that these are operators you get the right answer.

If you put the particle in a square potential with $x \in [0,L]$ the wave functions wind up being sine waves like

$$\Psi_n(x) \propto \sin ( k_n x). $$

with $k_n=n\pi / L$. The point is that when you put in the time dependence you get

$$\Psi_n(x,t)\propto\sin(k_n x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$

which is *not* a traveling wave. It's a standing wave which is moving neither left nor right. The expectation value of the momentum of this wave is zero even though the energy is not zero. To show this you just compute

$$\langle \hat{p}(t) \rangle \propto \int\Psi(x,t)\left( -i\hbar\frac{d}{dx} \right)\Psi(x,t)dx=-i\hbar k_n \int\sin(k_n x)\cos(k_n x)dx=0.$$

The energy, on the other hand, is

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle \propto \int\Psi(x,t)\left( -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \right)\Psi(x,t)dx=\frac{\hbar^2 k_n^2}{2m}\int\sin(k_n x)\sin(k_n x)dx \neq 0.$$

It is only in the case of a constant potential, in which the wave functions are

$$\Psi(x,t) \propto e^{i(k x - E t/\hbar)},$$

that you find $E=p^2/2m$:

$$\langle \hat{p}(t) \rangle \propto -i\hbar \int e^{-ikx}\frac{d}{dx}e^{ikx}dx=\hbar k.$$

Since the energy is

$$E = \langle H \rangle = \left \langle \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} \right \rangle \propto -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int  e^{-ikx}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{ikx}dx = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} = \langle \hat{p}^2 \rangle / 2m \equiv p^2/2m.$$

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the way of using kinetic energy to calculate momentum. It might work for certain special situations (could you provide reference of this), but generally the right way is to use the momentum operator.